# Processing text files for data extraction and analysis

Tags: performance, haskell, comparative-review

I started learning Haskell to see if I can use it at my job. A lot of my work is processing text files for data extraction and analysis.

For my first test, I added a counter at the end of each line from a .csv text file (currently I don't care about the format management).

My current code in Haskell is:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as L

addRecordId :: String -> String -> Int -> String
addRecordId "" _ _ = ""
addRecordId rec sep cnt = rec ++ sep ++ show cnt

addIncrementalId :: String -> [String] -> [String]
addIncrementalId _ []       = []
addIncrementalId sep ls = addId ls 1
  where
    addId []     _   = []
    addId (l:ls) cnt = addRecordId l sep cnt : addId ls (cnt + 1)

identifyFile :: FilePath -> String -> IO [String]
identifyFile path sep = do
  inpStr <- L.readFile path
  return (addIncrementalId sep (lines (L.unpack inpStr)))


printLnIdentifiedFile :: IO [String] -> IO ()
printLnIdentifiedFile ls = do
  lines <- ls
  putStr (unlines lines)

main = printLnIdentifiedFile (identifyFile "myfile.csv" ";")
```

This code processes a file of 1GB (4,845,000 records) in 90 seconds.

This C code below does the same job in 10 seconds:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  FILE *f = fopen("myfile.csv", "r");

  size_t bytes_read;
  size_t current_buffer_size = 400;
  char *buffer = calloc(current_buffer_size, 1);

  long cnt = 1;
  while ((bytes_read = getline(&buffer, &current_buffer_size, f)) > 0) {
    if (feof(f)) break;

    buffer[ bytes_read - 2 ] = 0;
    printf("%s;%ld\n", buffer, cnt++);
  }

  fclose(f);
  return 0;
}
```

And the Java code below does the job in 30 seconds:

```
package test.perf.numadr;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class NumAdr {

    static public void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {

            String sCurrentLine;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myfile.csv"));

            int cnt = 1;
            String lineWithId;
            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                lineWithId = sCurrentLine + ";" + cnt;
                cnt++;
                System.out.println(lineWithId);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }
}
```

For each test, I print the result to `stdout` and redirect to a result file.

My Haskell code is 3 times slower than the Java code and 9 times than the C code. 
As I'm a beginner in Haskell, I think my Haskell code is not the best.

How can I improve my program?

Comment: @ChriX (if you're still around), if your job includes a lot of text processing and data extraction, you should really learn the tools for the job: `sed`, `awk` and `perl`, in order of increasing complexity.  For instance—if I understand correctly that all this code does is append line numbers after a semicolon, you can do the same with `sed = filename | sed -n 'h;n;G;s/\n/;/;p' > outputfile`.  `sed` could be called the assembly language of text processing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think your program needs to be more Haskell-style (and shorter). Here is my rewrite:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as L

processContents :: L.ByteString -> L.ByteString
processContents contents = L.unlines out
    where out = zipWith f [1..] (L.lines contents)
          sep = L.pack ";"
          f n l = l `L.append` sep `L.append` L.pack (show n)

main = do
    contents <- L.readFile "myfile.csv"
    L.putStr (processContents contents)
```

Need better speed? It is trivial to convert this code into parallel one.

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as L
import Control.Parallel.Strategies
import GHC.Conc(numCapabilities)

processContents :: L.ByteString -> L.ByteString
processContents contents = L.unlines (out `using` parListChunk chunks rdeepseq)
    where out = zipWith f [1..] (L.lines contents)
          sep = L.pack ";"
          f n l = l `L.append` sep `L.append` L.pack (show n)
          chunks = 1 + (length out `div` numCapabilities)

main = do
    contents <- L.readFile "myfile.csv"
    L.putStr (processContents contents)
```

To compile it use the following command:

```
ghc -O2 -threaded -with-rtsopts=-N program.hs
```

Comment: Your code take the same time (12 secondes). But waouh!!! I think I must take a look to your code to understand everything :)

Comment: I use a few functions from standard library. Nothing fancy. Btw, now it is trivial to further increase performance by using parallel map and therefore utilizing all cores. :-)

Comment: I started learning Haskell for one week by reading the real world haskell and currently, I don't know the meaning of the black quote. What is its purpose?

Comment: It is just syntactic sugar for functions of two arguments. `a \`f\` b` is equivalent to `f a b`.

Comment: I forgot that! I've a lot of things to learn and remember :)

Comment: Out of pure curiosity, could you check the speed of the parallel code?

Comment: But doesn't the parallel code risk to change the records order?

Comment: No it doesn't. You only make pure code parallel, the IO is still sequential.

Comment: Oooops, when I launch the parallel code I get: Stack space overflow: current size 8388608 bytes. The result says me "Use `+RTS -Ksize -RTS' to increase it." But, I'm not understand what I must do :(

Comment: @ChriX, fixed. I forgot that ByteStrings are rather eager to evaluate. I wonder if it's any faster. It can be that IO is the bottleneck.

Comment: The parallel version is slower and I had to kill the process because my computer started hanging.

Comment: Too bad. It seems to me that the nature of the problem is too sequential to get any benefits from parallelization. Usually this simple approach can give surprisingly good performance boost.

Comment: FYI, you might try using `zipWith f [1..] (L.lines contents)` instead of `map (\ (a, b) -> foo) (zip [1..] (L.lines contents))`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, is that cosidered better style?

Answer (score 5):

An obvious bottleneck is the conversion to `String` and back. Try changing the type signatures to

```
addRecordId :: L.ByteString -> String -> Int -> L.ByteString

addIncrementalId :: String -> [L.ByteString] -> [L.ByteString]

identifyFile :: FilePath -> L.ByteString -> IO [L.ByteString]
```

[ByteString.Lazy.Char8](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.4.0/docs/Data-ByteString-Lazy-Char8.html) has its own `lines`, `unlines` and `putStr` which you can use, as well as `cons` or `append` for constructing your annotated line.